# How to add item to a folder in SharePoint list using GraphApi?

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

so I know how to add item to a list by POST

```
f"{graph_url}/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items"
```

But in this list I have specific folder where I want insert my item.
How the url should looks like?
Lets say {item_id} is the ID of the folder (which is another item on that list to be precise)
Should it be something like:

```
f"{graph_url}/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/item/{item_id}/items"
```

?

I went through documentation and couldnt find anything, is it even possible?
I just want to add item to a list to a specific folder in this list.

Comment: When I try this: "{graph_url}/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items/{item_id}" the resposne is:
{'error': {'code': 'invalidRequest', 'message': 'Invalid request', 'innerError': {'date': '2023-01-19T09:28:46', 'request-id': 'xxx', 'client-request-id': 'xxx'}}}

Comment: is it a documents list?

Comment: No, its a list with 'any' items which means I can create new column and add something there. I dont know if it is enough

Answer (score 0):

To update item in the folder of a SharePoint site you can use query:

```
PATCH /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}
```

Permission for this query:

[image]

For more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Hope this helps.